# Import CSV row into a dict?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This question has been asked before but in my scenario none of the answers apply.

I'm reading a csv file with this:

```
with codecs.open('./products.csv', 'r',  encoding="utf-8") as _filehandler:
    csv_file_reader = csv.DictReader(_filehandler)
    for row in csv_file_reader:
```

in my CSV file I have a column in a row that contains this:

```
'#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700', '#custom_green_paper': '338'
```

my goal is to add this to a dict.  The above column is in one column.

Here is an example of the data:

```
item,parse_dropdowns,fixed_dropdowns_values,links
postcards,"#quantity, #paper, #size, #color, #turnaround,  #coating","‘#custom_finishing': '497', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700', '#custom_green_paper': '338'",http://www.example.com/products/postcards
flyers,"#quantity, #paper, #size, #color, #turnaround, #coating, #folding","‘#custom_green_paper': '338', '#custom_hole_punch': '204', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700'",http://www.example.com/products/brochures
brochures,"#quantity, #paper, #size, #color, #turnaround, #coating, #folding","‘#custom_green_paper': '338', '#custom_hole_punch': '204', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700'",http://www.example.com/products/brochures
business cards,"#quantity, #paper, #size, #color, #turnaround,  #coating","‘#custom_green_paper': '338', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700', '#versionCustomerPulldown': '1'",http://www.example.com/products/businesscards
bookmarks,"#quantity, #paper, #size, #color, #turnaround,  #coating","‘#custom_finishing': '497', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700', '#custom_green_paper': '338'",http://www.example.com/products/bookmarks
calendars,"#quantity, #paper, #size, #color, #turnaround, #page, #coating","‘#custom_green_paper': '338', '#custom_finishing': '13356', '#custom_hole_punch': '205', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700'",http://www.example.com/products/calendars
```

The end goal would be to do have this:

```
{'#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700', '#custom_green_paper': '338'}
```

I thought this would be as easy as doing this:

```
dropdownValuesCsv = dict()
dropdownValuesCsv.append( row['fixed_dropdowns_values'] )
```

That failed.  Then I tried this:

```
dropdownValuesCsv = dict()
dropdownValuesCsv.update( row['fixed_dropdowns_values'] )
```

This produced this error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Then I tried this:

```
dropdownValuesCsv = { row['fixed_dropdowns_values'] }
```

but this produces a set which gives an error and is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add several rows of sample data from the `products.csv` file (including the initial header row).

Comment: @martineau Ok I added a screen shot of the csv.  Thanks for taking a look at this!

Comment: It would be better to open the csv file in a text editor and then  copy & paste the rows into your question. This will allow any answers to be tested before they're posted. It's impossible to do this with a screenshot showing what it looks like in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Modified code to use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead of the more powerful (and potentially more dangerous) built-in [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) because it's safer since that's all that's needed here.

Note that for testing I created a `products.csv` file from the data you added to your question—although I had to change the `‘` characters in it into `'` chars resulting in it containing this (because otherwise reading the file results in a `codec` error):

```
item,parse_dropdowns,fixed_dropdowns_values,links
postcards,"#quantity, #paper, #size, #color, #turnaround,  #coating","'#custom_finishing': '497', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700', '#custom_green_paper': '338'",http://www.example.com/products/postcards
flyers,"#quantity, #paper, #size, #color, #turnaround, #coating, #folding","'#custom_green_paper': '338', '#custom_hole_punch': '204', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700'",http://www.example.com/products/brochures
brochures,"#quantity, #paper, #size, #color, #turnaround, #coating, #folding","'#custom_green_paper': '338', '#custom_hole_punch': '204', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700'",http://www.example.com/products/brochures
business cards,"#quantity, #paper, #size, #color, #turnaround,  #coating","'#custom_green_paper': '338', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700', '#versionCustomerPulldown': '1'",http://www.example.com/products/businesscards
bookmarks,"#quantity, #paper, #size, #color, #turnaround,  #coating","'#custom_finishing': '497', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700', '#custom_green_paper': '338'",http://www.example.com/products/bookmarks
calendars,"#quantity, #paper, #size, #color, #turnaround, #page, #coating","'#custom_green_paper': '338', '#custom_finishing': '13356', '#custom_hole_punch': '205', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700'",http://www.example.com/products/calendars
```

Here's code that can read it and do what you want:

```
import ast
import codecs
import csv

COL_NAME = 'fixed_dropdowns_values'  # Column of interest.

with codecs.open('./products.csv', 'rb',  encoding="utf-8") as _filehandler:
    csv_file_reader = csv.DictReader(_filehandler)
    for row in csv_file_reader:
        dropdownValuesCsv = ast.literal_eval('{' + row[COL_NAME] + '}')
        print(dropdownValuesCsv)
```

And here's the dictionaries it creates and prints while reading the (modified) input:

```
{'#custom_finishing': '497', '#custom_green_paper': '338', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700'}
{'#custom_hole_punch': '204', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700', '#custom_green_paper': '338'}
{'#custom_hole_punch': '204', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700', '#custom_green_paper': '338'}
{'#versionCustomerPulldown': '1', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700', '#custom_green_paper': '338'}
{'#custom_finishing': '497', '#custom_green_paper': '338', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700'}
{'#custom_hole_punch': '205', '#custom_finishing': '13356', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700', '#custom_green_paper': '338'}
```

Comment: it is strange for me this just posts this to my console:  print(eval('{' + row['fixed_dropdowns_values'] + '}'))

Comment: It sounds like the print line was changed to `print("eval('{' + row[COL_NAME] + '}')")`, You should be seeing output similar to what's shown in my answer.

Comment: python 2.7? @martineau

Comment: FabricioG: Yes, 2.7.15. I changed my answer to do the same thing in a slightly different way, but the results are the same (as shown).

Answer (score 0):

I think there's just a points of confusion in your problem which will clear it up for you.

<strike>First off, it's unclear to me when you say that your CSV has one column with the value `'#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700', '#custom_green_paper': '338'`, as that includes a comma (and you haven't specified a different separator), so that should be two columns?  I'll be answering your question with the assumption that that's replaced with another separator (say, a semicolon).</strike>
Edit: this has since been clarified with the added screenshot.

I believe your main problem is that you're not considering the type of the output of `csv.DictReader`.  When it parses your csv, it will be mapping keys to strings, so when you attempt to update a dictionary with its output you're not getting the multiple values you want (just one string, which is implying these values).  We can get around this by parsing the strings though.

Here's my working example:

tmp.csv

```
fixed_dropdown_values, other
"'#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700', '#custom_green_paper': '338'", 'other': 'other'
```

test.py

```
import csv

dropdownValuesCSV = {}
with open('./tmp.csv') as file_handler:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_handler)
    for row in reader:
        # We split multiple key-value pairs by comma
        for mapping in row['fixed_dropdown_values'].split(','):
            # We do an additional split on a colon to differentiate keys and values
            # ... and do some extra cleanup to remove extra spaces and quotation marks
            key, val = [s.strip(' ').replace("'", '') for s in mapping.split(':')]
            dropdownValuesCSV[key] = val
print dropdownValuesCSV
# dropdownValuesCSV is:
# {'#custom_green_paper': '338', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700'}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The data is actually in one column.  I just added a screen shot of the data.  @Baozi

Comment: In that case, the reader will still output one large string (just with the comma separator), so you can just replace the semicolon with a comma in my answer and it should still work.

Comment: I get this when I print {'\xe2\x80\x98#custom_finishing': '497', '#custom_green_paper': '338', '#custom_shrink_wrapping': '700'}..  This appears to be an encoded error: \xe2\x80\x98 but if I just log this row[fixed_dropdowns_values] it does not show that. @Baozi

Comment: That does look like an encoding error.  In my example I simply opened my raw text file tmp.csv, but you may want to use your codec to open your csv.  I don't have more info on how your csv is encoded so I can't say for sure.  @martineau's answer does the same thing as my answer but uses `eval` directly on the line itself instead of parsing it, which should be fine for your purposes.  Hope you solved your problem.